# Check via JS if a program is installed for a url-type

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to read it via javascript ?

for example:

i have a link like this: mumble://mumble.piratenpartei-nrw.de:64738

and i would like to check if the program is installed.

best regards

Comment: please start by posting what code you've tried to write.

Comment: there is no code because there are no examples for this scenario. i thought that there is maybe some crazy workaround ^^

Answer (score 1):

This happens at the OS and/or Browser level and cannot be detected by JavaScript. There's no way to detect what software is installed on a machine with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

A hack, which is non-authoritative:

- If you can monitor the time that they click the app-link, and
- you monitor the time that they return to activity

then when the difference between these times is small, we can presume that the user did not leave the browser [to the linked app].